# Laravel 5.4 : Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using **Laravel 5.4** .There are two tables `groups` and `contacts` with the following structure. Every contact has a group.

#### contacts

[image]

#### groups

[image]

I also created a model for each one as below:

> Group.php which is the groups model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Group extends Model
{
    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contact');
    }
}
```

> Contact.php which is the contacts model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    public function group(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
    }
}
```

Now using the `php atrisan tinker`, the following command reports the error:

```
App\Contact::find(3)->group
```

When I type `App\Contact::find(3)` it returns the contact with ID 3 successfully but the `App\Contact::find(3)->group` returns the error while I expect it to return the group of contact with ID 3

Thanks.

---

## Update

This is error

[image]

Comment: seems you have problem with `group` keyword, I think it's already defined keyword.

Comment: @SagarGautam I renamed the function `public function group` to `public function ggroup` and tried `App\Contact::find(3)->ggroup`. It still reports the same error

Comment: Please add error on this

Comment: @SagarGautam I added the error

Comment: you forgot `return` keyword on group relation

Comment: @bhill77 Thank you very much. I can't believe I missed the `return` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
public function group(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
    }
```

instead

```
public function group(){
    $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
}
```

need to return

i am not sure if group is reserved word. check and change if it is.

Comment: The `group` is not a reserved word

Comment: why do you post same answer??

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi  where is the other answer like mine?

Answer (score 1):

make sure to return the relationship;

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    public function group(){
      return  $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
    }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I think group is a pre defined keyword, that might be the reason.

Comment: I renamed the function `public function group` to `public function ggroup` and tried `App\Contact::find(3)->ggroup`. It still reports the same error

Comment: namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    public function group(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
    }
}

Comment: add return type

Comment: I forgot to add the `return` keyword in groups model

Comment: ya i know, in my last comment send you the error. and solution also.